# Angular version 7 to upgrade 8 version - Getting NoModule metadata found for 'App1Appmodule'

Tags: angular8, upgrade

I have application which I need to upgrade it to latest version of Angular. I started upgrading it from 7 to 8. I have custom webpack.json file which we use to configure the file. My current application works with JSP.

Following is my Webpack Common file,

```
'use strict';

 const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
 const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
 const helpers = require('./helpers');
 const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

 module.exports = {

  entry: {
    vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
    'app1': isDev ? './src/app1-app.main.browser.ts' : './src/app1-app.main.browser.aot.ts',
    // use '_' to avoid javascript error in generated code
    'app1_dm': isDev ? './src/app1-app-dm.main.browser.ts' : './src/app1-app-dm.main.browser.aot.ts'
    },

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.scss'],
    // An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
    //  modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'style-loader', options: { sourceMap: isDev } },
                { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: isDev } },
                { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: isDev } }
            ],
            include: helpers.root('sass', '')
        },
        {
            test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
            use: [
                'to-string-loader',
                { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: isDev } },
                { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: isDev } }
            ],
            include: helpers.root('sass', '')
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'css/primengAssets/fonts/'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'css', to: '../css' },
        { from: 'fonts', to: '../fonts' }
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: helpers.root('src/index.html')
    })
]
 };
```

Webpack Dev File

```
'use strict';
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const ngw = require('@ngtools/webpack');
// const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
mode: 'production',

output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist/bundles'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},

optimization: {
    noEmitOnErrors: true,
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
    },
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    minimizer: [
        // new UglifyJsPlugin({
        //     cache: true,
        //     parallel: true
        // }),

        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
            cssProcessor: cssnano,
            cssProcessorOptions: {
                discardComments: {
                    removeAll: true
                }
            },
            canPrint: false
        })
    ]
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
            loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ngw.AngularCompilerPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.webpack.json',
        entryModules: ['./src/app1-app/app1-app.module#App1AppModule', './src/app1-app-dm/app1-app-dm.module#AppDMModule']
    })
]
});
```

I am getting below error:

**No Ngmodule metadata found for 'App1Appmodule'**